# Excel click to reference cell in formula not working

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

Hoping you can help! I'm having an issue with entering formulas in Excel 2010.

If I want to do a simple =A1 formula, I'm typing '=' in a cell then clicking on cell A1 to add it to the formula. However, what's recently started happening is I'm typing '=', clicking cell A1 which puts a little border around cell A1 (looks similar to the cell border when copying) but doesn't add the cell to the formula.

If I press the arrow keys it will move starting from wherever I've clicked, and start adding the cell reference to the formula.

Can't work out if I've accidentally clicked a hotkey of some variety or there's a bug in my excel!

Comment: Did the formula contain any symbol or existed function? Check the = is english language symbol.

Comment: Thanks, and no it's a brand new formula in a brand new cell. It is an english language symbol yes.

Answer (score 0):

Solved this. It was a bug in MS Paint where the functionality of the arrow keys navigating the page in Paint doesn't stop functioning when you select another window. Closing Paint fixed the problem.